# Вывод чисел Фибоначчи до заданной границы

Tags: java, числа-фибоначчи

Нужно сделать рекурсивный вывод чисел Фибоначчи вплоть до заданного числа. То есть следующее число Фибоначчи не должно превышать введенного пользователем значения.

```
private int fibNumbers[];

public void run() {
    println("What is the highest number");
    int n = readInt();

    fibNumbers = new int[n];
    fibNumbers[1] = 1;
    fibNumbers[n - 1] = fibonacci(n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        println(i + "-" + fibNumbers[i]);
    }
}

private int fibonacci(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
       return fibNumbers[0];
    }
    if (i == 1) { 
        return fibNumbers[1];
    }
    fibNumbers[i] = fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2);
    return fibNumbers[i];
}
```

Это то что я сделал для обычных чисел. Не могу придумать как сделать для заданного "максимального"

Comment: Посчитали очередное число последовательно. Если оно больше заданного, то прекратили работу. Иначе выводите на экран и начинаете считать следующее число.

Comment: То-есть сделать функцию бесконечной, но с условием?

Comment: "бесконечно" и "с условием" (то есть до определённого момента) - это таки противоположные вещи. У вас, кстати, функция не рекурсивно работает

Comment: Почему не рекурсивно?

Comment: Пардон, невнимательно посмотрел. Сбило с толку то, что вы в цикле для каждого `i` считаете. Размещу сейчас ответом свою идею

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если достаточно выводить сами значения чисел Фибоначчи (с первого), то коротко и относительно оптимально рекурсивное решение можно написать так:

```
private void fibonacci(int beforePreviousValue, int previousValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (previousValue <= maxValue)
    {
        System.out.println(previousValue);
        int currentValue = beforePreviousValue + previousValue;
        fibonacci(previousValue, currentValue, maxValue);
    }
}
```

И запустить, передав в качестве первых двух параметров `0` и `1` (нулевой и первый элементы последовательности соответственно):

```
fibonacci(0, 1, n)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я зациклился на том что бы использовать private int fibonacci, и совсем забыл про обычный воид

Comment: @LordNani на здоровье. Тут, на самом деле, ещё от условий задачи зависит: что можно передавать в метод и что нужно вывести на экран. Я исходил из наиболее оптимального варианта. Ваш вариант с `int fibonacci` и `for`-ом тоже можно доработать, чтобы ограничение срабатывало, но в нём очень неоптимально вычисляются сами элементы последовательности. Хотя можно попытаться его заоптимизировать